# How to find outliers in a Data Frame by group with X and Y coordinates in R?

Tags: r, coordinates, cluster-analysis, nearest-neighbor, outliers

I need to find outliers by coordinates and Groups in **R**.

My Data Frame looks like:

```
Name, Group, X, Y
Bob,  2, -300, 20
Karl, 4,  200, 10
Sara, 2, -298, 19
Hans, 4,  210, 12
Anna, 3, -700, 100
Maria,3, -690, 110
Lars, 2,  100, 50
etc.
```

I managed to make a ScatterPlot by Group which looks like:

```
22334444
22335544
11335552
```

But I didn't managed to get the outliers by Group with automatic Clustering (nearest neighbours?) as a new Dataframe.

(like Lars, he is far away from the other Persons from Group 2)

It would be nice to have a DF like

```
    Outliers_DF
    Name, Group,X,  Y
    Lars,  2,  100, 50
    Sam,   3,  900, 70
    Trixi, 11, 200 , 2
```

Comment: How about subsetting your data frame by group to give a matrix for each group, then running `hclust(dist())` on each? Outlying nodes will be merged at larger heights.

Comment: I tried using :hclust(dist(df[,5:6])) on one group. 5 and 6 are the X and Y colums        i only getting this:

Call:
hclust(d = dist(df[, 5:6]))

Cluster method   : complete 
Distance         : euclidean 
Number of objects: 2                               I don't understad what to do from here

Comment: How many observations and groups do you have? Perhaps give us a bigger sample of your df.

Comment: I have about 25000 observations per measurement and ca 70 Groups. An a Group can have between 1 and ca. 6000 observations. This means a group can be an outlier if it has for example only 1 Member. A group of 5000 who gather on two spots for example 2500 and 2500 has not outliers but if it gathers on two spots with 4995 and 5 the five people should be outliers... i this understandable? Sry English is not my motherlanguage

Comment: OK. I've added a proposed solution below. It works on the test data. See if it works on your big data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a loop that subsets your matrix by group and performs hierarchical clustering on the distance matrix of each subset. Then you can retrieve details of the most outlying observations from each `hclust` object in the output. First you take the group column and find the unique number of groups, then preallocate a list of this length for the output.

```
grpcol <- df$Group
ngroup <- unique(grpcol)
output <- vector("list", length(unique(grpcol)))
```

Now we run our loop: "For every group in `df`, subset the corresponding matrix, run `hclust` on its distance matrix, and put the resultant object in the preallocated list."

```
for (grp in ngroup) {
  mat <- df[df$Group %in% grp, -2]
  output[[grp]] <- hclust(dist(mat))
}
```

I've checked it works with this data frame `df` (note I added two extra people so it would work):

```
structure(list(Group = c(2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
X = c(-300L, 200L, -298L, 210L, -700L, -690L, 100L, -680L, 
220L), Y = c(20, 10, 19, 12, 100, 110, 50, 120, 14)), .Names = c("Group", 
"X", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Bob", "Karl", 
"Sara", "Hans", "Anna", "Maria", "Lars", "Person1", "Person2"))
```

To get the individual clusters, use `[` on the group you want, for example `output[2]`.

You'll want to extract values from `$height`, `$order` and `$labels`. (You can easily find how to do this by searching SO.) Also, you'll have to think of a criterion to decide what's an outlier, you could check out Cross Validated for good opinions on this.

Comment: I had to change the line : mat <- df[df$Group %in% grp, -2] because it didn't drop Group Column in mat <- df
 mat$Group <- NULL and now i have this Problem: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 27.8 Gb

Comment: Maybe you'll need to break down the data into smaller chunks. I can't really say without seeing the full data.

Comment: ok i figured out how to manage smaller chunks, but this line:                  mat <- df[df$Group %in% grp, -2]            doesn't work and i don't know why i always get : > show(mat)
[1] -2 is it possible to use another expression df[df$Group %in% grp, -2]? With your DF it works perfect

Comment: the dplyr DF was the Problem! Now I can reproduce your solution with my DF. I just have to figure out what to do with my output file. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you're getting there with it. You can get all the heights out using `unlist(sapply(output, "[", 2))`. The ones with bigger heights have further outliers. Also, if you do `plot(hclustobject)` you can get the dendrogram and check the outliers visually.

Comment: Also, if you think it's solved, could you accept the answer? (Or at least upvote if helpful!!!) :-)